# Why am I getting "cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener" error when I try to connect to oracle database from vscode?

Tags: oracle, database-design

I have a script I wrote to connect to my local oracle database. It worked perfectly before now. I was able to connect and populate the database with data from vscode. After I formatted my machine and reinstalled oracle database and instance client. I couldn't connect again, whenever I try, I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\ChiNedu\Documents\python\Oracle\oracle.py", line 10, in <module>
   cnx = cx_Oracle.connect(conStr)
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener
PS C:\Users\ChiNedu\Documents\python\Oracle>
```

when I type lsnrctl stat in command prompt, I get this

```
LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on 09-FEB-2023 17:33:46

Copyright (c) 1991, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=DESKTOP-QPAJR53)(PORT=1521)))
 TNS-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
  TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
   TNS-00515: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
    64-bit Windows Error: 1001: Unknown error
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
 TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
  TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
   TNS-00511: No listener
    64-bit Windows Error: 2: No such file or directory
```

I tried to change the HOST NAME but can't find the %ORACLE_HOME%/network/admin directory from my machine services. Please help me get this fixed. Thanks.

I searched for `listener.ora` in my machine and found it. Here is the details I got, I think the hostname is different. What is the hostname am supposed to use and how do I correct it?

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
   (SID_DESC =
    (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
    (ORACLE_HOME = C:\Oracle_db_home)
    (PROGRAM = extproc)
    (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\Oracle_db_home\bin\oraclr19.dll")
  )
)

LISTENER =
 (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
  (DESCRIPTION =
   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DESKTOP-QPAJR53)(PORT = 1521))
   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
  )
)
```

Here is the picture of the `listener.ora` files in my machine. I changed all to `listener.ora.bak` still it didn't work. Instead when i type `hostname` in cmd, it shows me no value for the hostname. [image: Listener.ora files] I changed all the hostname to `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: Is your machine still called "DESKTOP-QPAJR53"?  
Is the listener process actually started / running?

Comment: @PhillW. I changed my machine name to DV. I still get the same error when I try to connect to Oracle